# Saving multiple items in a ComboBox control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm working on a student grading system and I want a suggestion to save all the data that were entered in the TextBox Controls into a text file, but I'm facing a problem. In my program the student can select multiple courses from the ComboBox Control and enter a grade for each one of them.

How can I save all the selected items from the ComboBox control with the grades entered for the same student?

For example: A student enters his name **Adam K.**, and **Adam K.** selected six courses and put grades for each one of them.

How can I save all these pieces of information in order to be displayed like the following?

Adam K. , history 98/100, math 56/100, geography 78/100 and so on.

Comment: Can you clarify which framework are you working in - WPF, WinForms, ASP.Net etc.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a more complete explanation. a `ComboBox` only allows the user to select one item at a time so you only have to one set of data from your `TextBoxes` at a time. If you're saying that you want them to make another selection after that then you just do the same thing again. There's no multiple selections in the `ComboBox` at the same time.

Comment: @StewartRitchie im working in WinForms

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes i know you cant select multiple options from a combBox , in my program every time the student selects a course and enters a grade they press on a submit button to be able to enter another course and grade. i just want to display those information in a text file

Comment: You don't "just" want to do something. You want to do something specific and you need to describe that specific thing. A vague description that isn't even accurate is not good enough. If you want to store the data from a `ComboBox` and some `TextBoxes` multiple times for multiple selections then that's still doing it for one selection multiple times, so you only need to know how to do it for one selection. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of your SPECIFIC problem. What have you tried and what happened when you tried it? Think about the specific steps and try to implement them.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I would suggest using a ListView rather than a ComboBox. Just add the Subjects as column headers, and then let the student fill in the grade for each column (set the LV's LabelEdit property to True). That way it's already displayed nicely on screen, and after that, it's trivial to save the contents of the ListView to a txt file using something like `WriteAllText`. You probably don't even need to add the "/100" to each since it's automatically assumed that the max is 100. See my mockup: https://i.imgur.com/pndNiTs.png

Comment: Where are they entering the grades? How is a grade associated with a course? What does 78/100 mean? Is it 78 points out of 100? You need to respond and edit your question soon. You already have 2 close votes.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein thank you for the help it made more sense using a list view, thank your for your answer much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the information you describe is not very clear, I can only try to provide you with a solution based on the information you provide.

The effect is as follows:

[image]

In `test.txt` file:

[image]

You can try my method if you want this effect.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim name As String
    Dim info As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim course As String() = {"History", "Math", "English", "Chinese", "Science", "Biology"}
        For Each item As String In course
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If ComboBox1.Text IsNot "" Then
            If TextBox2.Text Is "" Then
                Try
                    info.Add(ComboBox1.Text, "0 / 100") 'score default
                Catch
                    MsgBox("The course " & ComboBox1.Text & " already exists.")
                End Try
            Else
                Try
                    info.Add(ComboBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text & "/100")
                Catch
                    MsgBox("The course " & ComboBox1.Text & " already exists.")
                End Try
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Please enter course info")
        End If

        ComboBox1.Text = "" 'clear course info
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        name = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox3.Text &= name & "   "

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In info
            TextBox3.Text &= kvp.Key.ToString & ":" & kvp.Value.ToString & "   "
        Next kvp
        TextBox3.Text &= vbCrLf

        TextBox1.Text = ""
        info.Clear() 'clear all info

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter 'Write Text to Files with a StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\test.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
        file.Close()

        TextBox3.Text = "" 'Append to Text Files in Visual Basic
        'Dim inputString As String = "This is a test string."
        'My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("D:\test.txt", inputString, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: perfect that is exactly what i needed thank you so much even though i wasnt really clear you hit the nail in the right spot

Comment: @Julie, very neat solution you have there, I upvoted it. May I suggest using "Using file As System.IO.StreamWriter" ?

Comment: @evry1falls, of course you can. `Using` is a safer way when you use file.